# Need help finding the name of an HTML variable

Tags: html, variables, edit, document, mode

There is an HTML variable called something along the lines of "document.openEditMode" that went set to true, allows for editing of the page's text in-browser by just clicking and typing anywhere. I've forgotten what the actual name is and I can't find it on Google by the description. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [document.designMode](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#designMode)